# Add a link to the respective review task in the votes tab

Tags: feature-request, review, voting, vote-to-close

Exactly as the title says, in the votes tab, for each vote if it was made in a review task, I suggest adding a link to that respective review task. This way users can go back and look at what other people voted for the same review task.

For example, say I was doing a review task and voted to close a question that I wasn't entirely sure about. After I vote to close it, I click the back button and notice that I was the first person to vote on it, so I'm still unsure if it was the right decision or not. A few days later I am on my votes tab and but notice it's still open, so I can click to see that I was the only one out of several voters that voted to close it, so I know I may have been a bit harsh with that vote.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't *exactly* what you're asking for, but it is useful:

Under [your "all actions" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/811240/mike?tab=activity), there's [a "reviews" subtab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/811240/mike?tab=activity&sort=reviews). That shows your review history from all queues. Clicking your verdict on the left (e.g. "Looks OK") takes you to the corresponding review task ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/13860140)), while clicking the post name just takes you to the post.

[image: what to click]
<sup>image edited to move the subtabs left so the picture isn't super wide</sup>